# Can lcov/genhtml show files that were never executed?

Tags: gcc, code-coverage, lcov

How can I make `lcov` and `genhtml` show files that are not linked / loaded? I'm using it to show test coverage and I would like to see every source file appear in the HTML report, even if it has zero coverage. That way I can use lcov to identify source files that are missing tests. The missing source files have a .gcno file created for them, but not a .gcda file.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example code which replicates this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to see all files you have to create a baseline coverage data file with -i option.
After capturing you data you have to combine the two files with -a option.

There is an example in lcov man page (https://linux.die.net/man/1/lcov):

> Capture initial zero coverage data.
>
> Run lcov with -c and this option on the directories containing .bb,
>   .bbg or .gcno files before running any test case. The result is a
>   "baseline" coverage data file that contains zero coverage for every
>   instrumented line. Combine this data file (using lcov -a) with
>   coverage data files captured after a test run to ensure that the
>   percentage of total lines covered is correct even when not all source
>   code files were loaded during the test.
>
> Recommended procedure when capturing data for a test case:
>
> 1. create baseline coverage data file
>
>    ## lcov -c -i -d appdir -o app_base.info
> 2. perform test
>
>    ## appdir/test
> 3. create test coverage data file
>
>    ## lcov -c -d appdir -o app_test.info
> 4. combine baseline and test coverage data
>
>    ## lcov -a app_base.info -a app_test.info -o app_total.info

You then have to use the app_total.info as source for genhtml.